# I need to identify a number stored in array

Tags: php

I have an array that storing numbers between 1 and 31. The numbers need to be echoed as a select drop down options.

```
$number = array();
echo '<select id=\'day\'>';
for ($i = 0; $i < 31; $i++)
{
   $number[] = $i;

echo '<option value=\'{$number[]}\'>{$number[]}</option>';
}
echo '</select>';
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't even need to build an array:

```
for ($i = 1; $i < 32; $i++) echo '<option value="'.$i.'">'.$i.'</option>';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use array_fill() to make the array (http://ca.php.net/array_fill)

Or just echo out the numbers as you iterate from 1->31.

Beyond that, wrapping your number in the appropriate HTML for a select box should work. Could you expand on the question?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
print '<select name="foo">';
foreach($number as $n){
  print "<option value=\"$n\">$n</option>;
}
print '</select>';
?>
```

Though as other posters pointed out, why bother building an array when you could just `for($i = 1; $i < 32; $i++){ print "<option value=\"$n\">$n</option>"; }`?